# Autologin DropBox and OneDrive (SkyDrive) Issue

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api, onedrive

I am integrating dropbox core api and OneDrive (SkyDrive) api in my application having issue how remember user is logged in or not in application.

Issue arises

1. Session is valid or not.
2. Access token and refresh token.

Always asking user permission on re-login (Not want to show) in both